# Is it possible to deploy Trac with fine grained authentication?

Tags: python, authentication, nginx, gunicorn, trac

I'm trying to setup nginx, gunicorn, supervisor and trac, it is all working fine, even the static files which I asked for help here some days before... but the authentification. How does it works??

I know about the basic/digest authentification with nginx... but is there any plugin or something to have authentification without to setup basic/digest authentification in nginx? I mean, is there some web-based authentification?

I've found an AccountManager plugin, but seems that it has been discontinued or it doesn't receive any update (at least for installation directions)

If it is not posible to setup trac with some kind of web/psql authentification, tell me about an alternative based in python, please.

I'm considering taiga because it's based on django at the back and looks very good, but I'm afraid it goes private software in the future, so i wanted to find a completely open source solution here.

Thanks

Comment: [AccountManagerPlugins](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin) is still being developed. A new release is needed, so I suggest installing from the trunk. The [ConfigurationCookbook](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/CookBook/AccountManagerPluginConfiguration) describes how to setup alternate password stores such as `SessionsStore`. Could you describe in more detail what type of authentication you would like?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "fine grained authentication". In Trac, [fine grained permissions](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFineGrainedPermissions) allow access control for individual resources.

Comment: I wanted to have an account for each user and to manage them all from the web. This is a production server. Thanks

Comment: AccountManagerPlugin may be the right choice for you in that case. Let me know if you have trouble configuring it.

Comment: Yes please. show me how to setup the plugin because I been trying to setup it without succes.

Comment: What authentication store are you trying to use?

Comment: I wanted to use the same db of trac (postgresql).

Comment: [SessionStore](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/CookBook/AccountManagerPluginConfiguration#SessionStore) will technically store the credentials in the database, but it appears that it's not the same as using [psql authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-methods.html). You could take a look at some of the [plugins](https://trac-hacks.org/tags/accountmanager?wiki=on&blog=on&ticket=on) that work with AccountManager , such as [SQLAuthStorePlugin](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/SQLAuthStorePlugin), or write your own plugin to work with AccountManager's API.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm considering taiga because it's based on django at the back and
>   looks very good, but I'm afraid it goes private software in the
>   future, so i wanted to find a completely open source solution here.

Taiga developers here! Taiga is not going open source in the future. We will charge for private projects, but public projects will always be free and Open Source self-hosted version will always be available. So please, don't worry about this or write us to our mailing list (some people asked this already) 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/taigaio

We are happy that you considered Taiga.